# Is there any elegant way to execute specific code depending on the caller, using reflection or otherwise?

Tags: c#

In my ideal world, what I'm looking for would exist as something along the lines of this:

```
public string UserDefinedField
{
    get { return _userDefinedField; }
    internal set { _userDefinedField = value; }        
    set { _userDefinedField = value; ChangedFields.Add(Fields.UserDefinedField); }
}
```

Where one statement is executed regardless of the access modifier, and another statement is executed if it's called from an external assembly or class.

I'm sure I could code something by using reflection and checking up the current call stack to see if the caller is in the same assembly, but I'm looking to see if there's a more elegant approach than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public string UserDefinedField
{
    get { return _userDefinedField; }
    set { SetField(value); ChangedFields.Add(Fields.UserDefinedField); }
}

// Call this from internal methods and use the public property for other cases
internal string SetField(string userValue)
{
    _userDefinedField = userValue;
}
```

You **could** get the caller information by [examining the calling stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) but that is extremely slow (compared to the above) and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Redefining Isak's Answer

```
public string UserDefinedField
{
    get { return InternalUserDefinedField; }
    set { InternalUserDefinedField = value; ChangedFields.Add(Fields.UserDefinedField); }
}

internal string InternalUserDefinedField 
{
    get { return _userDefinedField; }
    set { _userDefinedField= value;  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're asking, but in a case like that, I would use an internal method to set the value directly.

```
...
internal void SetUserDefinedField(string val) {
  _userDefinedField = val;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in the reflection route, this code looks like it'd work, but I'd be hesitant to use it over the other suggestions posted so far:

```
// assumes callers know where they're located at in the current stack trace.
private Boolean IsExternallyCalled(int methodDepth)
{
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();

    System.Type callingType = trace.GetFrame(methodDepth).GetMethod().ReflectedType;
    System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(callingType);

    return !(a.Equals(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()));
}
```

The problem I have with the other examples posted so far are the fact that other classes, even in the same assembly, require internal knowledge of how this particular class operates in order to call the "correct" setter.  This doesn't smell as it would if I placed the same constraint on outside assemblies, but I'd rather separate my concerns out a tad more.